# Block Adobe Add-Ins in Office365

Tags: office365, adobe-acrobat

Every time I remove the Adobe add-ins from my Office365 applications, they eventually reappear. Since Adobe updates automatically, it's apparent that the updates are the likely culprit.

I can't find any info, though, on how to prevent their continual re-infestation of my Office apps. I've poked around settings for both Office365 and Adobe/Creative-Cloud.

Comment: The add-ins I'm trying to get rid of are in the Office365 apps; not sure if those are the ones you're calling "necessary"? If so, I've removed them from the Office apps with no problems. I have other Adobe apps (Photoshop, Lightroom), so do not desire to remove CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this about updating the [Installer](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/features.html). It's removed the add-ins; I'll have to wait and see if they return after the next update to Acrobat.

UPDATE: The link is for the Enterprise version, but the process works on my non-Enterprise Acrobat. There is a file, AcroPro.msi, that is in a subfolder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Setup Files`. Running it allows me to turn off all the Office add-ins in one shot.

Comment: Rather than just having a link (which could go dead at some point in the future), you might want to edit your answer to also provide an excerpt from that source so that whatever it is that helped you remains here even after the link stops working.

Comment: Nah. Makes too much sense. (Thanks for the thought; update is forthcoming).

Comment: It's been a couple weeks and the add-ins continue to be absent. I'm confident now that this approach is an acceptably long-term solution.